# ELSEIF Command Not Found PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Confused as to why this section of code wouldn't be working.

```
144       #Evaluate Column C
145       $COLUMNC = $_.C
146    
147       #Find Prepared With:
148       $COLUMNCOUT = $COLUMNC -like "*Prepared*"
149       if($COLUMNCOUT -eq $True){
150            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNC
151       }
152    
153       #Find Contains:
154       $COLUMNCOUT = $COLUMNC -like "*Contains:*"
155       elseif($COLUMNCOUT -eq $True){
156            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNC
157       }
158       
159       else{
160            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"R") = $COLUMNC
161       }
```

I believe what I have is correctly written.  Can I not have line 154 where it is???

Any help is appriciated.

ERROR:

```
elseif : The term 'elseif' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\TEST\Working_Test.ps1:155 char:4
+    elseif($COLUMNCOUT -eq $True){
+    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (elseif:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\TEST\Working_Test.ps1:159 char:4
+    else{
+    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Despite the errors the code still works as intended.....

Comment: You have an unrelated line of code between the closing curly brace of the `if` statement and the `elseif` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right you should write it this way:

```
$COLUMNC = $_.C
if ($COLUMNC -like "*Prepared*") {
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNC
}
elseif ($COLUMNC -like "*Contains:*") {
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNC
}
else{
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"R") = $COLUMNC
}
```

Comment: You may mark the other answer as valid as it is more descriptive than mine.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:
**No code between the curly brackets and the elseif**

If you put a line of code between these statements powershell throws an error, because there is no if clause directly before the elseif clause.

How your code should look like:

```
#Evaluate Column C
$COLUMNC = $_.C

#Find prepared with
if ($COLUMNC -like "*Prepared*") {
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNC
}

#Find Contains:
elseif ($COLUMNC -like "*Contains:*") {
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNC
}
else{
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"R") = $COLUMNC
}
```

---

More about if and else-if expressions here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/if_else_statement_in_powershell.htm

---

Best regards
Nicicalu

Comment: I need that line of code to run before my next elseif, how would I achieve that?

Comment: You don't. You can put the comparison inside the if condition.

Comment: @TylerColeman I edited the answer now. You can compare the variable directly in the if statement and don't need another variable.